# Google Business API

Tags: google-maps, google-business

I need to use Google Business API to access information of a particular category of business from a particular location. Can it be done using Google business API or Google MAPS API?

Answer (score 1):

The [Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details) is open and offers the following details if you know the placeId of the location:

> Basic
>
> The Basic category includes the following fields: address_component,
> adr_address, business_status, formatted_address, geometry, icon,
> icon_mask_base_uri, icon_background_color, name, permanently_closed
> (deprecated), photo, place_id, plus_code, type, url, utc_offset,
> vicinity.
>
> Contact
>
> The Contact category includes the following fields:
> formatted_phone_number, international_phone_number, opening_hours,
> website
>
> Atmosphere
>
> The Atmosphere category includes the following fields: price_level,
> rating, review, user_ratings_total.

The [Google Profile APIs](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/locations) are restricted and offer the following details if you also own or manage the respective location:

- languageCode
- storeCode
- title
- phoneNumbers
- categories
- storefrontAddress
- websiteUri
- regularHours
- specialHours
- serviceArea
- labels[]
- adWordsLocationExtensions
- latlng
- openInfo
- metadata
- profile
- relationshipData
- moreHours[]
- serviceItems[]